# How to display tabs below action bar

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I have placed tabs in action bar and it is working fine. but when i rotate device it will appear on the action bar. Is there any way to always display that tab below action bar like [image]

Answer (score 2):

Used the following function which force to show stacked tabs

```
private void forceStackedTabs(ActionBar ab)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ab instanceof ActionBarImpl)
            {
                // Pre-ICS
                disableEmbeddedTabs(ab);
            }
            else if (ab instanceof ActionBarWrapper)
            {
                // ICS
                try
                {
                    Field abField = ab.getClass().getDeclaredField("mActionBar");
                    abField.setAccessible(true);
                    disableEmbeddedTabs(abField.get(ab));
                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private void disableEmbeddedTabs(Object ab)
    {
        try
        {
            Method setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod = ab.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", boolean.class);
            setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.setAccessible(true);
            setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.invoke(ab, false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I commented the if-else if because I don't konw what you meant by ActionBarImpl and ActionBarWrapper and it works. Thanks! (If you want to explain that to me that'd be awesome :D)

Comment: Hey I have place a comment regarding same. Before ICS 4.0 ActionBar was instance of ActionBarImpl class and from ICS it is instance of ActionBarWrapper class. Test this functionality on different OS.

Comment: THANK YOU! Your code works well for me. Additional note: I think the ActionBarWrapper applies only if you use ActionBarSherlock library. In my case, I don't and android default implementation is its internal ActionBarImpl class.

Comment: @Sandy - I tried to use this. But I am getting exception like java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mActionBar
In my code, ActionBar variable is being declared as _actionBar.
So, I changed the line Field abField = ab.getClass().getDeclaredField("mActionBar"); as Field abField = ab.getClass().getDeclaredField("_actionBar");
But still, I am getting the similar exception. Any idea on this?

Comment: Can you help me with the ActionBar i.e used of supportlibrary v7. I am getting no such method error.