# UI change in two different android devices

Tags: android, user-interface

I have two android smart phones. Both are samsung galaxy S2, but one is at&t and other is Orange. I have done implementation and it shows my screen as shown in the image 1.

Image 1

[image]

Once I ran the code in orange phone then it showed the display as shown in the image 2.

Image 2

[image]

My problem is how did the action bar got swap with tab bar in my orange phone. Both the screen sizes are same. I want to change the orange phone UI as shown in the image 1.

Comment: You may have `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) ` change it to `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true) ` or remove it. Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047686/how-to-display-tabs-below-action-bar

Comment: yes that did the trick, but I don't want to show app icon in my action bar. (I want to show only the app name). This step made the app icon visible in the app

Comment: If you don't want the icon to show up in actionBar then add `getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);` in onCreate() method of activity